# Ошибка при выполнение кода JS в Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript

После сохранения файла с расширением js и попытке запустить код выдает:
code language not supported or defined

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете выполнить в Visual Studio файл. Это невозможно. в Visual Studio нужно создать проект, возможно - включить его в solution, и уже в рамках этого проекта добавить файл.

Почему? Потому что когда у Вас есть файл, и вы хотите его "выполнить", возникает множество неявных вопросов. В каком окружении должен выполняться файл? Это для браузера или для node.js? Какой версией js'а его надо выполнить? Куда деть "результат выполнения"?

На все эти вопросы "отвечает" проект. В проекте зафиксировано окружение, в котором исполняется код.

Ну, и последний вопрос: Вы не путаете, часом, Visual Studio и Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Сейчас исправлюсь

Comment: Если речь о Visual Studio Code - возможно, Вам достаточно поставить расширение, что то типа live server?

Comment: Завтра буду пробовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Делал всё по видео курсу, но Что-то идёт не так......

Comment: Может, запостить в вопрос ссылку на курс?

Comment: https://youtu.be/CxgOKJh4zWE

Comment: То, о чём спрашиваю находится где-то в конце первого часа... 57я минута приблизительно..... Дальше пока не дошел.

Answer (score 1):

Ребята, нашёл ответ!!
/Спасибо тем, кто подключился к обсуждению!/
(Дело в том, что я ещё Совсем Новичок в JS)
Загвоздка была вот в чём:
"Студио" -почему-то- Автоматически ставит мне язык html вместо JS - это видно на Нижней Панели..... - Приходится всё время - после закрытия-открытия файла менять язык Вручную. ....... С этим ещё надо Разбираться - как Автоматически выставить JS!!
Нашёл выход - задав вопрос в гугле и читая инструкцию по "Студио".

Comment: Кросавчег, как пишут в этих самых интернетах. Сам нашел, в чем проблема, и не поленился написать для других! Так держать!

Answer (score 0):

Вы js так не запустите на голом VS Code. Или через [подобное](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38768079) расширения или внутри HTML файла и в браузере.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать и разбираться.